# json value javascript XDK

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, intel-xdk

I'd like to do a little REST API in my Intel XDK application.
My PHP file returns values like :

```
{"Name1":12,"Name2":34,"Name3":67}
```

Now I can access to my values with this code, on a onclick event :

```
  var json_string = request.responseText;
  var json = JSON.parse(json_string);
  intel.xdk.notification.alert(json.Name1, "Name 1");
```

It works, I have the first value for Name1 : 12.

Now I want to add an input text to insert the value I want. Instead of using "json.Name1", I want to do it dynamically. 
So I tried to add an input text :

```
<input id="test" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder">
```

And getting the value :

```
var value = $("#test").val();
```

Finally, I tried :

```
intel.xdk.notification.alert(json.value, "Name 1");
```

But it doesn't work. 
How can I add a value from an input to have JSON value? I would like to obtain the value of Name1, Name2 or Name3 if I write it in the input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a key in `json` with the *name* from an `input`...

```js
var json = {"Name1":12,"Name2":34,"Name3":67};

alert(json[document.getElementById('test').value]);
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder" value="Name1" />
```

JQuery...

`json[$("#test").val()]`

Comment: In this case, alert will show me "Name1" for example no? Not the related value for "Name1" in the json table.

Comment: The last line in the answer _should_ alert `12`, but I don't follow the question exactly. You have values in `json`. Do you want to populate `input` fields with those values? Or populate `json` with values _from_ the `input` fields.

Comment: Ok thanks. If I write "Name1" in 'input' field, I want to obtain "12" in alert box.